# How to make a flowing liquid animation in Android

Tags: android, animation

I want to know how do I make a flowing liquid like animation in Android. I need a few ideas for this. Is it possible to do it in Android?

**EDIT**
As per the link given my @amitsingh in the comments below, the question can be expanded as follows. I need to use the LiquidFun physics library in an Android activity to achieve fluid animation. My aim is not creating a game but just to create an animation of that sort.

Thanks

Comment: check this- http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/12/new-tools-to-take-your-games-to-next.html

Comment: yes this is a good one! is the code available for this engine?

Comment: As per the link given my @amitsingh, the question can be expanded as follows. I need to use the LiquidFun physics library in an Android activity to achieve fluid animation. My aim is not creating a game but just to create an animation of that sort.